# Azure WebJobs SDK 3, trying to add a BlobTrigger and related connection string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

The old way of doing things looked as so:

```
        var jobConfig = new JobHostConfiguration(cfg.DocumentDatabase.BlobStorageServer)
        {
            NameResolver = new Support.BlobNameResolver(_env)
        };
        jobConfig.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_pollSeconds);

        _wjHost = new JobHost(jobConfig);
```

I am trying to translate this to the new way in 3.0, and this is how far I have come:

```
        _wjHost = new HostBuilder().ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorage(x =>
            {
                x.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_pollSeconds);
            });
        }).ConfigureServices(s =>
        {
            s.AddSingleton<INameResolver, Support.BlobNameResolver>(_ => new Support.BlobNameResolver(_env));
            s.Configure<QueuesOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_pollSeconds);
            });
        }).Build();
```

Firstly, i don't know which `MaxPollingInterval` is the right one to use... so i set both. I assume i shouldn't be using the one in `AddBlobStorage`

Secondly, and more importantly, where do I specify the blob storage connection string? In the case above, it's the setting stored in `cfg.DocumentDatabase.BlobStorageServer`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after staring at the source code for the webjob SDK, I found a kludge. Well, I think it's a kludge. It works and I can now use the new 3.0 SDK.

I am posting this here, mainly because I fear there is no other way to do this using my own configuration files.

If this is wrong, please just let me know and I will delete this answer.

So my code now looks like this:

```
    _wjHost = new HostBuilder().ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorage(x =>
        {
            x.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_pollSeconds);
        });
    }).ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddSingleton(new StorageAccountProvider(new BlobStorageConfiguration(cfg.DocumentDatabase.BlobStorageServer)));
        s.AddSingleton<INameResolver, Support.BlobNameResolver>(_ => new Support.BlobNameResolver(_env));
        s.Configure<QueuesOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_pollSeconds);
        });
    }).Build();
```

The line I added was `s.AddSingleton(new StorageAccountProvider(new BlobStorageConfiguration(cfg.DocumentDatabase.BlobStorageServer)));`

The webjobs SDK is specifically looking for a key named `Storage`. So I had to implement `IConfiguration` and kludge this in as so:

```
private sealed class BlobStorageConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    private readonly string _bsConnString;
    public BlobStorageConfiguration(string connString)
    {
        _bsConnString = connString;
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get => key == "Storage" ? _bsConnString : null;
        set { }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> GetChildren() => null;
    public IChangeToken GetReloadToken() => null;
    public IConfigurationSection GetSection(string key) => null;
}
```

and now the trigger is firing just fine. Not pretty. But there is ZERO documentation on the new IHost methods.

Comment: Thank your for your sharing. You can mark it as answer so that it would helpful for others:)

Answer (score 4):

Official sample available at [WebJob Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/tree/dev/sample/SampleHost)

In your Functions, you can pass the connection string key name used in 
`appsettings.json`

ex:

```
public void ProcessBlob([BlobTrigger("blobPath", Connection = "AzureWebJobsBlobConnection")] string blob)
```

the "AzureWebJobsBlobConnection" is configured in `appsettings.json` as follows:
`{
  "Logging": {
    ...
  },
  "AzureWebJobsBlobConnection": "...",
}`

And do not forget to add the configuration in `program.cs`:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, cb) =>
            {
                IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

                cb.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorage(o => 
                {
                    o.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
                })
                .AddServiceBus(c =>
                {
                    c.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1;
                });
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((webHostBuilder, loggingBuilder) =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hb, sc) =>
            {
                string connectionString = hb.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

                sc.AddScoped<Functions, Functions>();
                ...
            });

        builder.RunConsoleAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in that sample where you set the connection string. Could you please illustrate this point? That's what this question was asking.

Comment: @Andy i added an example using the same logic of the official GitHub

Comment: In the code example, `connectionString` is unused. Surely that's not correct?

Comment: @PeterTaylor it is just an example how to get a connection string, sure in my code i register a `dbcontext` and use the `connectionString`

Answer (score 1):

In the WebSDK 3, the job is configured via the `appsettings.json` file, the same way it's done for ASP.NET Core.

You can see an example [on the official Github repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/sample/SampleHost/Program.cs), but I'll also add a more complete example below.

In `appsettings.development.json`, configure it to use the local storage, via the `ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsStorage"]` property:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

And in `appsettings.json`, configure it for prod:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=key",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=name;AccountKey=key"
  }
}
```

My complete `Program.cs` looks like this (with comments):

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();

        // allows us to read the configuration file from current directory
        // (remember to copy those files to the OutputDirectory in VS)
        builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        // configure things like batch size, service bus, etc..
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b
            .AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
            .AddAzureStorage(options =>
            {
                options.BatchSize = 1;
                options.MaxDequeueCount = 1;
            })
            ;
        });

        // this step allows the env variable to be read BEFORE the rest of the configuration
        // => this is useful to configure the hosting environment in debug, by setting the 
        // ENVIRONMENT variable in VS
        builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        });

        // reads the configuration from json file
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;

            // Adding command line as a configuration source
            config
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            if (args != null)
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
        });

        // configure logging (you can use the config here, via context.Configuration)
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();

            // If this key exists in any config, use it to enable App Insights
            var appInsightsKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appInsightsKey))
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(o => o.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey);
            }
        });

        // inject dependencies via DI
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<INameResolver>(new QueueNameResolver("test"));

            services.AddDbContextPool<DbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext"))
            );
        });

        // finalize host config
        builder.UseConsoleLifetime();

        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone came to the same situation I had with resolving the queue name when you use QueueTrigger:

You have to use " Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection " package for the below code to work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Environment : {(string.IsNullOrEmpty(environment) ? "Development" : environment)}");

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });

        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {

            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorage();
            // b.AddTimers();

            b.AddServiceBus(c =>
            {
                c.ConnectionString = "[Your Connection String]";
            });
        }).ConfigureServices((context, services)=>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<INameResolver>(new QueueNameResolver(config));
        });

        var host = builder.Build();


        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }

public class QueueNameResolver : INameResolver
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public QueueNameResolver(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
    public string Resolve(string name)
    {
        return _configuration[$"AppSettings:{name}"];
    }
}
```