# How do I register a custom NameResolver with the new HostBuilder in WebJobs SDK 3.x?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

There are a lot of examples on the internet on how to do this with the old JobHost, but none I can find with HostBuilder.

Thanks,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I didn't found detailed documentation on the new HostBuilder.

However looks like we could use this code to do it. You could find it on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/sample/SampleHost/Program.cs).

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // add some sample services to demonstrate job class DI
                services.AddSingleton<ISampleServiceA, SampleServiceA>();
                services.AddSingleton<ISampleServiceB, SampleServiceB>();
            }
```

And there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53179508/10383250) about it, which uses the same service to implement it, you could try it.

Comment: The "answer" link above is VERY useful concerning the context in which one uses the above registration, i.e. AddSingleton<>